# PHP Email & Hyperlinks

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, html-email

I'm trying to include a hyperlink in my email but it is just showing as plain text. I'm probably just miss-using my quotes in the $BODY section and I'm just not seeing it.

```
echo "Activation Code: " . $emailString . " <br>";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts 
(name, pass, email, activated, code) VALUES('$user', '$pass', '$email', 'false', '$emailString') ") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$to = "$email";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = '<html><head></head><body> Thank you for registering! Please go to this address to activate your account: <a href="'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] .'/PHP%20project/activate.php?activationCode='.$emailString.'">' .$emailString . '</a> </body></html>';
$from = "From:---@gmail.com";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from, $headers)) {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} else {
    echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` does not include the protocol http:// or https://, so the link without a protocol would not function. .

Comment: Maybe you should encode the `href` attribute with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php just to be safe. And probably you should insert a space after `From: `.

Comment: You can also put the entire $body into double-quotes so you don't have to keep going back and forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using it wrong:

```
 mail($to, $subject, $body, $from, $headers)
```

The [`mail()`](http://php.net/mail) function does not have a `$from` parameter. You ought to throw it into `$headers` as well.

Comment: Updated the code and @Michael it was the http:// I completely forgot. Thank you! :)